# Android Studio Suddenly Crashed and now showing error

Tags: android

I am creating an app since two months and today it suddenly crashed and when i try to open Android Studio its showing this...

```
 Internal error. Please refer to https://code.google.com/p/android/issues

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io/netty/channel/ChannelHandler
at com.intellij.idea.StartupUtil.lockSystemDirs(StartupUtil.java:464)
at com.intellij.idea.StartupUtil.prepareApp(StartupUtil.java:184)
at com.intellij.ide.plugins.MainRunner.lambda$start$0(MainRunner.java:45)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: io.netty.channel.ChannelHandler
at com.intellij.util.lang.UrlClassLoader.findClass(UrlClassLoader.java:307)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
... 4 more
```

---

```
JRE 1.8.0_162-b12 amd64 by Oracle Corporation
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_162\
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems your android studio is corrupted... I once had the same problem. you can uninstall and re- install the latest version again... i had the same problem . the problem was solved after re-instaling it....

Comment: Thanks ! This solved the problem. I uninstalled the android studio and installed again and now its opening like before.

Answer (score 0):

Try Invalidate cache / Restart (I resolved when my Android Studio misbehaving like code is visible in gibberish)
You can also try deleting the cache folder which looks like this
C:\Users\Ganesh-PC.AndroidStudio4.0\system

Comment: My android studio doesn't even open . When i try to open it shows this error.

Comment: I didn't experienced this. But my guess Android studio may have been corrupted or uninstalled.

Comment: Try to reinstall the Android studio. May work for you. But don't import settings when installing